# Angular.js + Play Framework, make it SEO friendly

Tags: angularjs, scala, playframework, prerender

I have a Play Framework 2.3.4 application with Angular.JS frontend.
I need to make my website accessible for search bots and I'm trying to install [play-prerender](https://github.com/Jarlakxen/play-prerender) module. Readme tells me to add specific code to my project to make it work. Where exactly should I put it? I have created a new Scala file with this code inside my App folder, but it does nothing. 
Maybe there are another way to solve my problem?

Comment: Did you add the dependency to the build.sbt?

Comment: @Zee Yeah, I have no errors on build

Comment: @Kirakishou, have you taken a look at [the documentation on the Global object](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/ScalaGlobal#The-Global-object)?